# basic java array method

Tags: java, arrays

My job is to write a method named `findLastIndex`, this method receives an array and an integer value representing an element of the array. `findLastIndex` searches through the array to find the given element and returns the index the last time this element is found in the array (the position of the element closest to the length of the array). In case the element is not found in the array, the method returns -1.

So my current code looks the following:

```
public static int findLastIndex(int [] nums, int element){
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(i == element){
            return nums[i];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

But I have no idea how to not return the first time , but to make it return the last times the element was found.

Comment: Let's say I give you a book of 1000 pages, and I ask you to find the last page where the word "hello" appears. Where do you start looking? The first page?

Answer (score 3):

You simply save the (currently) last index while looping through the array:

```
public static int findLastIndex(int [] nums, int element){
    int lastIndex = -1
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] == element){
            lastIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return lastIndex;
}
```

But, maybe the better option is to search from the end of the array:

```
public static int findLastIndex(int [] nums, int element){
    for(int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(nums[i] == element){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static int findLastIndex(int [] nums, int element){
       int count = 0; //counts the iterations of the enhanced for loop
       int index = -1;//stores the index that the element is currently in

  for(int x : nums){//enhanced for loop
       if(x==element){index=count;}//if element is found in the array it stores the index and will override it if it is found again
       count++;//counts iterations
  }
  return index;//returns the index
```

}

Saw other people gave good answers... figured I would give it a try for fun.